# Adding two buttons to rightBarButtonItems not working

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I am not sure why the following code is not working:

```
UIBarButtonItem *newButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"New" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(newClicked:)];

UIBarButtonItem *shareButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(share:)];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:newButton, shareButton, nil];
```

It only display the "newButton" UIBarButtonItem on the navigation bar and not the "shareButton" button.

Comment: I just copy and paste your code in my app and it works as it should.
Any ways try by renaming your objects e.g. newButton, shareButton

Comment: isn't the 'new' a reserved word?

Comment: even though it works, it's a bad idea to name vars like that. The 'newButton' name is not following naming conventions either. When i do not know how to name a var, i usually name it the same way as the class is named i.e. UIBarButtonItem* barButtonItem = ... I had compiler errors in some circumstances(dont remember what exactly) when i had a var named 'newSomething'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the problem had to do with code following the questioned code:

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 44)];
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Marker Felt" size:26.0];
label.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.5];
label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
label.textColor =[UIColor whiteColor];
label.text=self.title;
self.navigationItem.titleView = label;
[label release];
```

Posting this now in case someone else encounters this problem!

Comment: can you please explain how did this fix the problem? Is it the titleView that has something to do with the problem?

Answer (score 3):

I found a different issue involving this behavior.

If you've set a custom `titleView` (`navigationItem.titleView = ...`) then the navigation item can sometimes hide your buttons except the first one if it doesn't have room.

So make sure you limit the `width` of your custom `titleView`.

Answer (score 2):

**rightBarButtonItems** is in ios 5.
I think the issue is with the objet name `new`, please change this to any other name like `newButton` or something like that.
Because new is a keyword used for `memory` `allocation` in `C++`